# Why are Symfony roles stored as "json" doctrine type?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony5

Since we will just be storing short simple strings here, why is it presented as the default option when we could be using a simpler `simple_array`? Is it just a matter of preferences?

Answer (score 1):

My wild guess would be:

`simple_array` uses simple `explode`/`implode` to deserialize/serialize data, which does not offer any sort of escaping of a comma.

Example:

```php
$arr = ["some,foo","and","another","bar"]; // Notice that the first string contains ",". 

echo implode(',', $arr);
```

This produces `some,foo,and,another,bar`, but notice exploding would produce array of 5 elements (not 4):

```php
["some","foo","and","another","bar"]
```

This would clearly produce invalid behavior in the app.

There was a feature request opened a couple of years ago about this, but it was closed exactly in favor of using the JSON type:
https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3300

Comment: Pretty sure json is the default because most databases now support it as a  native column type.  Array and simple_array are just text types and mean nothing outside of Doctrine.

Comment: IMO, CSV is still a valid and widely accepted data format and does have a meaning outside of Doctrine. However, for the `array` type I agree. For me, it has no real value not only outside of Doctrine but PHP as well... (in terms of managing data by hand)

Comment: CSV has a meaning at the database table level but I am not aware of any major database engine that understands CSV as a column type.  This is in contrast to json where, for example, you can query against individual json attributes in a reasonably efficient way should the need arise.